# Appending string to git revert commit message without opening editor

Tags: git, shell

We use an internal tool on the commandline to trigger reverts on our master branch. A typical call is like

```
$ supertool revert SOME-TICKET
```

Internally this PHP tool runs

```
...
$result = shell_exec("git revert -m1 --no-commit <COMMIT HASH>");
...
```

for all commits associated with `SOME-TICKET`.

I'm fine with the default commit message of the revert commit

```
Revert "<MESSAGE>"

This reverts commit <COMMIT HASH>.
```

What I now need to do is to append a line to that message, to make it look like:

```
Revert "<MESSAGE>"

This reverts commit <COMMIT HASH>.

<ADDING A LINE HERE>
```

If I execute `git revert` in a terminal, an editor opens and I can manually edit the commit message. But how can i pass in a message to `git revert` in an interactive environment, when the `revert` command is issued by another program?

Ideally our tool could `shell_exec` this command:

```
$result = shell_exec("git revert -message='...' -m1 --no-commit <COMMIT HASH>");
```

But I couldn't find such a parameter in the `git revert` docs https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use any of the sequencer based commands (revert and cherry-pick) and use `--no-commit`, these leave their default message in `.git/MERGE_MSG`, where `git commit` will pick it up for further editing.  It's therefore possible to simply append to that file, then `git commit --no-edit` the result.

This is, as you've noticed, not documented anywhere and hence it might break in the future.  To avoid that you might want to just generate your own commit message.  For instance, as a shell script, if you want to revert commit `$H`, adding extra text `$extra`:

```
git revert --no-commit $H
[pause for user interaction as needed/desired]
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
printf >$tmpfile 'Revert %s\n\nThis reverts commit %s.\n\n%s' \
    "$(git log --no-walk --pretty=format:%s $H)" \
    $H \
    "$extra"
git commit -F $tmpfile
rm $tmpfile
```

(fancy this up more as needed, e.g., add trap code to remove the temp file on exit and/or signal; a `-t` argument to `mktemp`; and so on).

Note that when reverting a merge, the `sequencer.c` code produces more than just the usual `This reverts ...` message:

```
    if (opts->action == REPLAY_REVERT) {
            base = commit;
            base_label = msg.label;
            next = parent;
            next_label = msg.parent_label;
            strbuf_addstr(&msgbuf, "Revert \"");
            strbuf_addstr(&msgbuf, msg.subject);
            strbuf_addstr(&msgbuf, "\"\n\nThis reverts commit ");
            strbuf_addstr(&msgbuf, oid_to_hex(&commit->object.oid));

            if (commit->parents && commit->parents->next) {
                    strbuf_addstr(&msgbuf, ", reversing\nchanges made to ");
                    strbuf_addstr(&msgbuf, oid_to_hex(&parent->object.oid));
            }
            strbuf_addstr(&msgbuf, ".\n");
    } else {
```

You can, of course, follow this as well, if you choose not to rely on `.git/MERGE_MSG`.

(Incidentally, for all occurrences of `.git`, use `git rev-parse --git-dir`.)

Comment: is it possible to put it as hook?

Comment: @ShipluMokaddim: if you're using `--no-commit`, there's no hook invoked: neither cherry-pick nor revert invoke one directly.

Answer (score 0):

With Git 2.37 (Q3 2022) offers an alternative which could avoid any script/hook:

"[`git revert`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bfca6316345ffd717c717d2e36365239a3070124/Documentation/git-revert.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert))</sup> learns `--reference` option to use more human-readable reference to the commit it reverts in the message template it prepares for the user.

See [commit 191faaf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/191faaf72648c4ed080a9e38c1782bc1619a6e87) (31 May 2022), and [commit 43966ab](https://github.com/git/git/commit/43966ab3156a082067bf9930351e96e9488da735) (26 May 2022) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bfca631](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bfca6316345ffd717c717d2e36365239a3070124), 15 Jun 2022)</sup>

> ### [`revert`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/43966ab3156a082067bf9930351e96e9488da735): optionally refer to commit in the "reference" format

> A typical "[`git revert`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/43966ab3156a082067bf9930351e96e9488da735/Documentation/git-revert.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert))</sup> commit uses the full title of the original commit in its title, and starts its body of the message with:
>
> ```
> This reverts commit 8fa7f667cf61386257c00d6e954855cc3215ae91.
> ```
>
> This does not encourage the best practice of describing not just "what" (i.e.
> "Revert X" on the title says what we did) but "*why*" (i.e.
> and it does not say why X was undesirable).
>
> We can instead phrase this first line of the body to be more like
>
> ```
> This reverts commit 8fa7f667 (do this and that, 2022-04-25)
> ```
>
> so that the title does not have to be
>
> ```
> Revert "do this and that"
> ```
>
> We can instead use the title to describe "why" we are reverting the original commit.
>
> Introduce the "`--reference`" option to "`git revert`", and also the revert.reference configuration variable, which defaults to false, to tweak the title and the first line of the draft commit message for when creating a "revert" commit.
>
> When this option is in use, the first line of the pre-filled editor buffer becomes a comment line that tells the user to say *why*.
> If the user exits the editor without touching this line by mistake, what we prepare to become the first line of the body, i.e.
> "`This reverts commit 8fa7f667 (do this and that, 2022-04-25)`", ends up to be the title of the resulting commit.
> This behaviour is designed to help such a user to identify such a revert in "[`git log --oneline`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/43966ab3156a082067bf9930351e96e9488da735/Documentation/pretty-options.txt#L31)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---oneline))</sup> easily so that it can be further reworded with [`git rebase -i`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/43966ab3156a082067bf9930351e96e9488da735/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L501)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt--i))</sup> later.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/43966ab3156a082067bf9930351e96e9488da735/Documentation/config/revert.txt#L1-L3):

> ### `revert.reference`
>
> Setting this variable to true makes `git revert` to behave
> as if the `--reference` option is given.

`git revert` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/43966ab3156a082067bf9930351e96e9488da735/Documentation/git-revert.txt#L120-L128):

> ### `--reference`
>
> Instead of starting the body of the log message with "This
> reverts `<full object name of the commit being reverted>`.",
> refer to the commit using "`--pretty=reference`" format
> (cf. [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)).
>
> The `revert.reference`
> configuration variable can be used to enable this option by
> default.